# How to add a custom new row at the very end in a Laravel 8 SpatieQueryBuilder?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

In Laravel 8, I have a query that selects things from a table. I would like to add a row at the very end of a SpatieQueryBuilder that tells the sum of each column.

```
return parent::query()
        ->select([
            'order.id',
            'order.store',
            'order.total',
        ])
```

This is in the query() function of the OrderBuilder.php. I would like to have a row at the end that shows the total, have the store say 'Total', and the Total say the total of all the rows' totals. Is there any way I can do that in SpatieQueryBuilder? And should work with filters too, like if i only want to show stores A and B. ?filter[store]=A.

Existing table:
| Store | Total |
| -------- | -------------- |
| A | 11 |
| B | 22 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 2 |

What I want from spatie:
| Store | Total |
| -------- | -------------- |
| A | 11 |
| B | 22 |
| C | 1 |
| D | 2 |
|Total | 36 |

I am using MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `DB::raw()` like this :

```
return parent::query()
    ->select([
        'order.id',
        'order.store',
        'order.total',
         DB::raw('column1 + column2 + column3 + ... as total')
    ])
```